# Error : An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I am trying to Add a new Entity in DB though while adding i am getting following error :

```
 ERROR : An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

The Object class looks something like this:

```
public partial class orders
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public orders()
    {
        this.details = new HashSet<detail>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    public decimal id { get; set; }
    public decimal locationID { get; set; }
    public decimal contactID { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<detail> details { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()] 
    public virtual contact contact { get; set; }
    public virtual location location { get; set; }
}
```

`locationID` and `contactID` are foreign key value towards `location` and `contact` tables . Both `contact` and `location` also have references to some other tables in them.

I have set the values for `contact` and `location`. The respective `id` of `location` and `contact` in there tables are having

`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` option and should be generated on `savechanges()` of order table and mapped in `locationID` and `contactID` . These values are generated by a trigger in DB.

The code for saving the data is as below

```
foreach (DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry in _db.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToArray())
        {

            if (dbEntityEntry.Entity != null)
            {
                dbEntityEntry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
            }
        }                                                               
        _db.Entry(order).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
        _db.orders.Add(order);
        _db.SaveChanges();
```

I am very new to all this and it is possible i am not understanding how the referenced entities insert works.

Also it is not possible for me to handle the generation of ID on code side .

Can you guys please help me out on this?
Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason that you're using the change tracker? For general use, you should just use your `DbContext` (`_db`) and `Add` item and then `SaveChanges`. ChangeTracker is automated by the operations you make over the entity once you fetched it from your DbContext.

```
  _db.orders.Add(order);
  _db.SaveChanges();
```

That should be all, unless there is something else you haven't mentioned.

Comment: i was using _db.ChangeTracker.Entries() because i was getting the same issues earlier i wanted to find all attached entities and then remove all of them so that there may not be any issues while adding , though same issue occurs even after it.

Comment: @user8546638 Are you using a singleton dbContext?? If you're having "entity is already attached" errors, that means you have entities left in same dbContext but didn't save their changes.. maybe in other threads if you're working multi-thread with one dbContext.. the best practice is never using a singleton dbContext, but creating and disposing a dbContext for each operation you want to do in your methods.